# Compiler option not working for unordered set C++11 feature

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 x64, using Eclipse Indigo w/ CDT plugin, and my g++ version is 4.7.3. I have added the compiler option `-std=c++11` and the same option to discovery options (even though the code did not autocomplete when I wrote it).

Eclipse underlines parts of the following in red and gives warnings. However, the program, when run (ignoring errors), prints the expected result (`Compiled with gcc 4.7\n 1 0\n`). How can I fix this behavior?

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_set<int> s; // Symbol unordered_set cannot be resolved
    cout << "Compiled with gcc " << __GNUC__ << '.' << __GNUC_MINOR__ << endl;
    s.insert(0); // Method insert cannot be resolved
    s.insert(1); // Method insert cannot be resolved
    s.insert(0); // Method insert cannot be resolved
    for(auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) cout << ' ' << (*i);
        // Method begin and end cannot be resolved
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what Eclipse calls in command line:

```
...$ gcc -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 .../specs.c
Using built-in specs.
...
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04)
```

After turning off the `-std=c++11` compiler option for my `C` compiler (as it shouldn't be needed there anyway) - **but** keeping it on for the `C++` compiler, the output printed to the console is as follows.

```
...$ g++ -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 .../specs.cpp 
Using built-in specs.
...
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04)
```

And, regardless of the errors Eclipse shows me, the output is still the same, showing the unordered set works and was compiled properly. This is clearly just an issue before the build. If my indexer isn't parsing properly before the build, how is the set working at runtime?

Comment: Could be you have more than one version of GCC installed, and Eclipse somehow ends up using the wrong one? (Insert something like `std::cout << "Compiled with gcc " << __GNUC__ << '.' << __GNUC_MINOR__ << std::endl;` in your code to have it output the GCC version used to compile it.)

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, I do have multiple versions of GCC installed, but your code returns "Compiled with gcc 4.7" - which should have c++11, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And from 4.7 onward, the C++11 option was indeed `-std=c++11` (it used to be `-std=c++0x` in 4.6 and earlier). So, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is the right version, but the include files for the Standard library are not. I haven't configured Eclipse for multiple GCC versions in a while, but isn't there an option for the include directories somewhere? Perhaps it takes them from the wrong GCC installation.

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, that's why I'm stumped. I followed c++11 activation to the dime, and it still doesn't work. Should I delete my old gcc installation (how would I do that?)? The project explorer has an "Includes" directory in my project - and it shows the unordered_map file - I'll post a picture. Thanks for your time, btw.

Comment: Screenshots are counterproductive. Dig up the logs and look at the actual command line with the actual compiler flags.

Comment: @n.m. Should I remove all of the screenshots?

Comment: Find the command line, then decide if it conveys the same information as the screenshots.

Comment: @n.m. I selected the "Show output in a dedicated console" option, but g++ was never invoked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up because there was simply nothing else I could do, purged my my system of eclipse and my `~/.eclipse` folder, downloaded Kepler and its CDT version, and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler you are using may not include support for C++11, check your man page or IDE documentation and it will tell you if there is support or not.

Comment: My g++ and gcc version is also 4.7.3, so they should both support `unordered_set` at the very least

Comment: The GCC/G++ 4.7.1 that I compiled on Mac OS X certainly works OK with `-std=c++11` and accepts your original code.  Do you have multiple versions of G++ on the machine?  Is Eclipse using the version you expect?  Try adding `-v` to the options; it reports on lots of information about what the compiler is doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please see my comment on the question itself in response to jogojapan

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the file's extension is `.c` instead of `.cpp` (or `.cc`), which causes it to be compiled with `gcc` instead of `g++`.

This means it is treated as pure C code instead of C++11, which makes it unsurprising that it won't compile.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can confirm that my file's name is `main.cpp` and Eclipse recognizes that extension as a C++ source. Also, the unordered set works as expected. This is just an issue before the build.

Comment: And that's the thing - it _does_ compile! It's not running on an old version of the compiled code either - adding a `s.insert(2)`, sure enough, makes the output `2 1 0`.